Is this the correct value for integrating this differential form over a sphere?
I posted this problem but made a mistake. I redid my work and got another sensible looking answer (the volume of the unit sphere). Does this look like a correct solution? This isn't an assigned problem; I'm doing it to practice and learn the theory.

Problem Statement:
The unit sphere is defined as
$$ S^2 = \{ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1\} \subset \mathbb R^3$$ and $ i : S^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ is inclusion map. Have form $$ \omega = \left( x^2 - x + yz\right) dy \wedge dz$$
on $\mathbb R^3$. Calculate $\int \limits_{S^2} \omega$

Answer Attempt:
Represent pullback $(i^{-1})^*$ as $i^{-*}$.
NOW,
$$ \int \limits_{S^2}\omega =  \int \limits_{i^{-1} \circ \,i  \, \circ S^2}\omega = \int \limits_{ i \circ S^2} i^{-*} \omega$$
Under the pullback, take the parameterization of coordinates as
$$ \begin{align}
&i^{-*}x  = \cos \theta \cdot \sin \varphi \\  
&i^{-*}y  = \sin \theta \cdot \sin \varphi \\ 
&i^{-*}z  = \cos \varphi
\end{align}
$$
where $\theta \in [0, 2 \pi]$ and $\varphi \in [0, \pi]$. Then
$$
x^2 - x + yz \mapsto  (\cos \theta )^2 \cdot (\sin \theta)^2 - \cos \theta \cdot \sin \theta + \sin \theta \cdot \sin \varphi \cdot \cos \varphi
$$
The inclusion operator maps the sphere into the compact space $$i S^2 = [0 , \pi] \times [0, 2\pi] $$
Recall also that
$$ i^{-*} \left( dy \wedge dz \right) = d i^{-*} y \wedge d i^{-*} z$$
Thus, compute
$$ \begin{align} i^{-*} (dy \wedge dz) &= (\sin \varphi \cdot \cos \theta \cdot d\theta  + \sin \theta \cdot \cos \varphi \cdot d \varphi ) \wedge (- \sin \varphi \cdot d \varphi ) \\ &= \boxed{ -(\sin \varphi)^2 \cdot \cos \theta \cdot d \theta \wedge d \varphi }\end{align}$$
Then
$$ 
\begin{align}
i^{-*}(x^2 \cdot dy \wedge dz) &= (\cos \theta )^2 \cdot (\sin \varphi)^2 \cdot -(\sin \varphi)^2 \cdot \cos \theta \cdot d \theta \wedge d \varphi   \\
&= \boxed{(\cos \theta)^3 \cdot -( \sin \varphi)^4 \cdot d \theta \wedge d \varphi}
\end{align}
$$
and
$$ 
\begin{align}
i^{-*}(x \cdot dy \wedge dz) = \boxed{(\cos \theta)^2 \cdot -( \sin \varphi)^3 \cdot d \theta \wedge d \varphi}
\end{align}
$$
and
$$ 
\begin{align}
i^{-*}(yz \cdot dy \wedge dz) = \boxed{-( \sin \varphi)^3 \cdot \cos \varphi \cdot \sin \theta \cdot \cos \theta \cdot d \theta \wedge d \varphi}
\end{align}
$$
Split the integral for each summand and integrate $i^{-*}(x^2 \cdot dy \wedge dz)$ , $i^{-*}(x \cdot dy \wedge dz)$, and $i^{-*}(yz \cdot dy \wedge dz)$ separately.
Note that the first and third terms go to zero. Specifically, for the first term:
$$ \int \limits_{0}^{2 \pi} (\cos \theta)^3 d \theta = 0$$
and for the third term
$$ \int \limits_{0}^{ \pi} (\sin \varphi)^3 \cdot \cos \varphi \cdot d \varphi = 0$$
For the second term, however,
$$   \int \limits_{0, 2\pi} \int \limits_{0, \pi} (\cos \theta)^2 \cdot - (\sin \varphi)^3 \cdot d\varphi\wedge d \theta= - \left({4 \over 3}\right) \pi$$
Then we have that
$$ \boxed { \; \int \limits_{S^2} \omega = - \left({4 \over 3}\right) \pi \;} $$

This is correct, except for a sign/orientation issue. With the usual orientation (unit normal pointing outward), you need the $2$-form $d\varphi\wedge d\theta$ to get a positive area form. So the integral should be the negative of what you have.

@TedShifrin Thanks Ted, and you're correct. Of course, I could instead map the domain into $[0, 2\pi] \times [0, \pi]$ and treat clockwise as positive, yeah? Regardless, I kept parameter domain counterlockwise implicit and would need to take your step.
Yesterday you asked me if I knew generalized stokes theorem? I do, but can it be used in some way to help integrate this form? $\omega$ doesn't look exact to me, so I don't know how it could factor in here. Curious what you meant.

What is $d\omega$ (on $\Bbb R^3$)? Note that your given $2$-form on $S^2$ is actually globally defined.

@TedShifrin $d \omega = (2x-1) \cdot dx \wedge dy \wedge dz $? Then $S^2 = \partial B^3$, and $i B^3 = [0, 1] \times [0, \pi] \times [0, 2\pi]$, and $i^{-} dw = r \cdot \cos \theta \cdot \sin \varphi \cdot i^{-}(dx \wedge dy \wedge dz)$?
If I did that all correctly then that IS clever! I'll go integrate that.

By symmetry, the $x$ integral is $0$, so it’s easy!
